# How does one create a single instance of Notification<T>?

Tags: .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive

Using Rx, is there a simple way to create a single `Notification<T>`?

The closest I've been able to find is:

```
T value = ..;
var notifyValue = EnumerableEx.Return(value).Materialize().First();
```

This seems rather roundabout. The constructors for `Notification<T>` are inaccessible, but is there a factory method that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Notification<T>` is an abstract base class.  You need to construct one of its subclasses, `OnCompleted`, `OnError`, or in this case `OnNext`.

```
var notifyValue = new Notification<T>.OnNext(value);
```